# Timestamp @ cell reference problems

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, reference

I have a Google sheet. I have merged a couple of cells to get a wider space for free text answers. I have two merged cells that is showing the date for last changed made in the  bigger merger. The script works good.

```
           
        function onEdit(e) {
  
        var row = e.range.getRow();        
        var col = e.range.getColumn();       

        if(col === 7 & row === 66){
         e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('E67:F67').setValue(new Date()); 
        }          

        if(col === 7 & row === 70){
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('E71:F71').setValue(new Date()); 
         }
         }
```

However, if I insert a row above this cells it's all falling apart. Anyone know how to work around it?

Comment: Did you want the merged cell with date to move down?  If so doesn't the row number change?  Try using a named range instead.

Comment: yes, i want the merged cell to move down and yes, cell reference is going mental ;-)... Do you know if the named range is the same name as given in the normal sheet window?